# PHP get multiple data from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to insert data from the LinkedIn API into a MySql database.

My PHP code is getting all the values from the Array which is not in the second level. I don't know how to explain this, but I'll include the Array structure below:

```
Array
(
    [person] => Array
        (
            [id] => ########
            [first-name] => ########
            [last-name] => ########
            [languages] => Array

            [skills] => Array
                (
                    [skill] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [skill] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Start-ups
                                )

                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [skill] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Business Strategy
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [skill] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Marketing Strategy
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 12
                                    [skill] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Management
                                        )

                                )



                        )

                )

            [email-address] => ########
            [phone-numbers] => ########
            [im-accounts] => ########
            [twitter-accounts] => ########
            [headline] => ########
            [picture-url] => ########
            [public-profile-url] => ########
        )

)
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
/* SKILLS */
    // An array to hold it temporarily
    $skills_arr = array();
    foreach ($array->skills->skill as $t) {
      // Cast it to a string to get the text value back
      $skills_arr[] = (string)$t;
    }

    // Implode the array to a string
    $skills = implode(', ', $skills_arr);
```

What i need is to get all the "Skills" and seperate them by comma ",".

If my code worked I would have got the following value as $skills = "Start-ups, Business-strategy, ...."

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested Foreach loop for this.Like

```
$skills_arr = array();
foreach($array['person']['skills']['skill'] as $val)
{
     foreach($val['skill'] as $res)
     {
         $skills_arr[] = $res['name'];
     }
}
echo $skills = implode(', ', $skills_arr);
```

Comment: Trying this and will get back. Thanks

Comment: This returns empty like my own code. I will add more of my own code to give more info

Comment: I think your older code is wrong see your Array at name->Start-ups. It breaks due to some reason you need to correct it first.

Comment: Hi. I change the foreach to: $array['skills']['skill'] as $val | This made me recieved following: 1, Start-ups, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

Comment: First change your older code and use one more loop.

Comment: This is my code for the .xml array loop: function XML2Array(SimpleXMLElement $parent)
    {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($parent as $name => $element) {
            ($node = & $array[$name])
                && (1 === count($node) ? $node = array($node) : 1)
                && $node = & $node[];
            $node = $element->count() ? XML2Array($element) : trim($element);
        }
        return $array;
    }

Comment: Yes this works! But for some reason i get all the arrays trimmed to 1 character? B, M, M, W, S, C, B, E, S, O, O, W, W, M, S, A, G, S, E, D, S, N, L, N, G, G, U, D, P, E, W, B, S, H, I, C, S, C

Comment: sry for caps in the comment